# Android custom ListView with radio button

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am using a `ListView` in `DialogFragment`. List is populated from `SQLite` database 
using `SimpleCursorAdaptor`.

Now I am using context menu to select an item from the list and everything is working fine, but I want to use radio button to select one item from the list instead of context menu.

Code in the DialogFragment:

```
package com.example.saggu.myapplication;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Saggu on 1/25/2017.
 */

public class DialogSTB extends DialogFragment  implements View.OnClickListener{

    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
    DbHendler dbHendler;
    ListView listViewStb;
    String TAG = "MyApp_DialogSTB";
    TextView stbcountUA;
    int stbcountUa;
    int custId;
    Button unAssign;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    EditText searchboxstb;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_stb, null);
        dbHendler = new DbHendler(this.getActivity(), null, null, 1);
        stbcountUA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totalStbsUnAssigned);
        listViewStb = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.stb_list_dialog);
        unAssign = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.unassign_button);
       searchboxstb= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchboxstb);
        searchboxstb.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                displaySearchList();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (searchboxstb.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    displaySTBList();
                }
            }
        });
        unAssign.setOnClickListener(this);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        custId = bundle.getInt("CUSTID");
        registerForContextMenu(listViewStb);
        displaySTBList();
        stbcount();
        return view;
    }

    //region Create all List
    public void displaySTBList() {
        try {
            Cursor cursor = dbHendler.getUnAssignedSTBs();
            if (cursor == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cursor is Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Record Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String[] columns = new String[]{
                    DbHendler.KEY_SN,
                    DbHendler.KEY_VC,
                    DbHendler.KEY_STATUS
            };
            int[] boundTo = new int[]{
                    R.id.stb_sn,
                    R.id.stb_vc,
                    R.id.stb_status
            };
            simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(),
                    R.layout.stb_list_item,
                    cursor,
                    columns,
                    boundTo,
                    0);
            listViewStb.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region Create Search  List
    public void displaySearchList() {
        String searchItem = searchboxstb.getText().toString();
        try {
            Cursor cursor = dbHendler.searchSTBToList(searchItem);
            if (cursor == null) {
                //    textView4.setText("Unable to generate cursor.");
                return;
            }
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                //  textView4.setText("No Customer Found");
                return;
            } else {
                //   textView4.setText("");
                String[] columns = new String[]{
                        //DbHendler.KEY_ID,
                        DbHendler.KEY_SN,
                        DbHendler.KEY_VC,
                        DbHendler.KEY_STATUS
                        //   DbHendler.KEY_SN
                };
                int[] boundTo = new int[]{
                        //R.id.pId,
                        R.id.stb_sn,
                        R.id.stb_vc,
                        R.id.stb_status
                        //    R.id.vc_mac
                };
                simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(),
                        R.layout.stb_list_item,
                        cursor,
                        columns,
                        boundTo,
                        0);
                listViewStb.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG,""+ex);

        }
    }


    //region context menu
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener listener = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                onContextItemSelected(item);
                return true;
            }
        };
        menu.add("Assign STB");
        for (int i = 0, n = menu.size(); i < n; i++)
            menu.getItem(i).setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        if (item.getTitle() == "Assign STB") {
            //entry in assigned column
            int stbId = (int) info.id;
            int assigned = custId;

            if (dbHendler.getSTBID(custId) > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Already Assigned STB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                dbHendler.assignSTB(new STB(stbId, assigned));
                dbHendler.SetStbID(custId, stbId);
                Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Now Assigned STB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           swapRefreshCursor();

            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.unassign_button);
        try {
            String stbSN = dbHendler.getAssignedSN(getActivity(),custId);
            dbHendler.unAssignSTB(stbSN); //from stb table
            dbHendler.unSetId(custId);    //From cust table
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unassigned cust: " + custId+" STB SN: "+stbSN, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            displaySTBList();
            stbcount();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //endregion
    public void swapRefreshCursor(){
        try {
            mCursor = dbHendler.getUnAssignedSTBs();
            simpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(mCursor);
            stbcount();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void stbcount(){
        stbcountUa= dbHendler.countSTBsUA;
        stbcountUA.setText("STBs:"+stbcountUa);
    }


}
```

Custom Layout for single item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="Serial No."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="MAC/VC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Serial No."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stb_sn"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="VC No."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stb_vc"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stb_sn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/stb_sn" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stb_status"
        tools:text="ON/OFF"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Status"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Status" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Status"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stb_sn"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stb_sn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

DialogFragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dip"
        android:id="@+id/stb_list_dialog"
        android:layout_weight="0.74"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Total:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/totalStbsUnAssigned"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/unassign_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/unassign_button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="UnAssign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/unassign_button"
        android:layout_weight="0.74"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stb_list_dialog"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you implementing [`onCreateContextMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnCreateContextMenuListener.html)in your fragment?

Comment: Yes, Context menu is working

Comment: You want the behavior like context menu(long tap pops up a menu) but the popup menu should have radio buttons? Is that so? You are referring to list twice in your question. It is kind of confusing what your desired behavior is.

Comment: I don't want to use the context menu for the list, I want the list is created when fragment starts and every item in  the list should have a radio button so the required row can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify your list view item layout to have a radio button. 
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:clickable="true">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/radio_button" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Serial No."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radio_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radio_button"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="MAC/VC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radio_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radio_button"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Serial No."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stb_sn"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="VC No."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stb_vc"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stb_sn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/stb_sn" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stb_status"
        tools:text="ON/OFF"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Status"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Status" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Status"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stb_sn"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stb_sn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You don't need a context menu. Remove that from your fragment code.

Comment: I have inserted the radio button in XML, this is visible in the list but now I can only click the radio button, OnItemClick does not get called.